# What are the effects of removing outdated Android SDK build tools

Tags: android, build

Is there a effect on build if I remove the outdated Android SDK build-tools current version is  20 I want to remove version >= 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this multiple times and Android(Eclipse) projects are still alive. Just remember first install the most recent *Android SDK Build Tools* package then uninstall older ones. Just to play safe.

If you get in trouble building the old project just install older one back. They are put nicely in a separate android-sdk-windows/build-tools/x.y.z/ subfolders. Eclipse uses the most recent one by default unless project.properties props give specific buildtool version. Usually you should not do it.